# Storing items of generic type

Tags: swift, generics

So I'm writing an app that uses the [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) library to parse our JSON. Works pretty well. However, I'm trying to find a way to cache the parsed types we get back. They're all implemented as structs. I tried something like this:

```
struct CachedItem <T: Decodable where T == T.DecodedType> {
    let value: T
    let cachedTime: NSTimeInterval

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        cachedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    }

    func isExpired() -> Bool {
        let currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        return ((currentTime - cachedTime) > 20.minutes)
    }
}
```

However, attempting to create a cache like this:

```
var cache: [NSURL : CachedItem]
```

fails with the error: "reference to generic type 'CachedItem' requires arguments in <...>", which I understand to mean I need to do something like this:

```
var cache: [NSURL : CachedItem<Item>]
```

Is there any way I can get what I want here? Or any other suggestions for caching generic types that aren't Objective-C based classes.

Edit:
For posterity, here's the `Cache` and `CacheItem` types I came up with after Rob's answer.

```
struct Cache {
    private var cache: [String : CachedValue] = [:]
    private let queue = dispatch_queue_create("Cache Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    mutating func setValue(value: Any?, forType type: String) {
        dispatch_sync(queue) {
            guard let value = value else {
                return
            }

            self.cache[type] = CachedValue(value: value)
        }
    }

    func valueForType<T>(type: String) -> T? {
        var result: T?

        dispatch_sync(queue) {
            guard let cachedValue = self.cache[type] where !cachedValue.isExpired() else {
                result = .None
                return
            }

            result = cachedValue.value as? T
        }

        return result
    }
}

struct CachedValue {
    let value: Any
    private let cachedTime: NSTimeInterval

    init(value: Any) {
        self.value = value
        cachedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    }

    func isExpired() -> Bool {
        let currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        return ((currentTime - cachedTime) > 1.minutes)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, all you can say about the types in this cache are that they're `Decodable`, and that really isn't telling you anything useful since they're already decoded. That leaves `AnyObject`. If this really is a "cache of anything", then `[NSURL: AnyObject]` or even `[NSURL: Any]` is appropriate. This puts a lot of ugliness on the consuming side to figure out its type, but that's basically the identical ugliness that you had to have used to parse the JSON (which fundamentally works with `AnyObject`).

Seldom do I suggest `AnyObject`, but in this case, it's probably appropriate if you really want one big cache (rather than a cache for each type, which would be preferable if possible).

Comment: Fortunately, the ugliness of parsing JSON was covered by Alamofire and Argo, so types are pretty clean when it comes to the actual `decode()` required by Argo. Now that I think about it, it seems like the casting logic would be the same whether the items were generic or not.

Comment: I'll take a look at a cache per type, but that seems a bit weird since there's only ever one item of each type in the cache at a time. I mean, I guess I could preset the cache for that case, but that seem even weirder.